# where to buy Sefer Ohr Yitzchak

Tags: jewish-books

Where can I buy a copy of the sefer Shailos and Tshuvos Ohr Yitzchak of Rabbi Yitzchak Abadi?

No seforim stores carry it anymore ,out of stock.

Comment: Is my question not valid?

Comment: It may be helpful to mention a geographical area, so people from that location can refer you to stores who carry out-of-print volumes. I also see the volume is available on hebrewbooks.org, so you can download it and bring the file to a print-shop who can print it and bind it for you. (The cost depends on how many pages, and the quality of the binding. I would imagine that "spiral" bound is the cheapest.) There are online services that do this as well.

Comment: Only the first volume is available on hebrewbooks.org. For the second volume see the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second volume has the following address to purchase the book:
הרב עבאדי
119 Carasaljo Dr.
Lakewood, NJ 08701
732-318-6520

Answer (score 4):

The Sefer is available online [here](http://www.wslibrary.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=2890).

Answer (score 3):

Its available on his Kollel Website: http://oheltorah.com/shop/

Answer (score 0):

Both volumes are sold at the annual [Seforim Sale](https://theseforimsale.com) in Belfer Hall at Yeshiva University.

---

### Edit 2/2/2020

Beginning today the 2020 Seforim Sale is open. Both volumes are currently available there for $30.75 each.